# Problems working with Arrays in Flash CS4

Tags: compiler-errors, flash-cs4

I'm trying to learn how arrays work, and I have come across a problem that I am having issues solving. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I keep receiving the following three errors:

1176:Comparison between a value with static type flash.events:MouseEvent and a possibly unrelated type int.

1067:Implicit coercion of a value with static type flash.events:MouseEvent to an unrelated type Number.

1176:Comparison between a value with static type flash.events:MouseEvent and a possibly unrelated type int.

```
var P1Numbers:Array = new Array();
var e:int=0;

function P1LowestScore(e:MouseEvent){
var P1Lowest:Number=P1Numbers[0];

for(e==1; e<P1Numbers.length; e++){
    if(P1Numbers[e]>P1Lowest){
        P1Lowest=P1Numbers[e];
    }else{
        lblPlayer1Lowest.text="ERROR!";
    }
}
lblPlayer1Lowest.text="Your lowest score is "+P1Lowest+".";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Well, your problem is that you first define the variable *e* as an int, but your function P1LowestScore has also has a parameter variable *e* of type MouseEvent. This variable shadows the int e instance variable in the function. Thus, you are comparing a MouseEvent with the length of the P1Numbers array, which is an int.

Another problem I see is with your for-loop. You are using a boolean expression (e==1) instead of an assignment expression (e=1).

I am not sure how P1LowestScore if invoked in your code, but I guess it is via a Mouse Listener?

Anyway, just change you int e variable to some other name (basically anything) and your error should vanish. Actually, you might as well declare the variable inside the for-loop declaration as you don't use it outside the loop. As such:

```
for(i:int = 1; i<P1Numbers.length; i++){
    //your code
}
```